# We can't log you in because of an issue with single sign-on. Contact salesforce admin for help

Tags: salesforcedx

[image]I have integrated Auth0 as an Identity provider and Salesforce as a Service provider using SAML 2.0
I have configured SSO settings on Salesforce and did SAML validation as well.
Below is the screen shot for reference. I believe if the SAML validation says OK on everything then we should be able to login to test the integration and be able to login to salesforce though Auth0 IDP. But I'm unable to login to SF, it says "We can't log you in because of an issue with single sign-on". Any help is appreciated.
[![enter image description here]

[image]